# Storing/Caching API Token in python

Tags: python, api

I am working with a third party api for which the authentication token expires every 2 hours. Is there any way to cache this and update when the token expires?

Comment: What do you mean by "third party api". is it a web interface?

Comment: What execution environment are you using, and how do you retrieve a new token? Perhaps you could use the keyring package to store?
https://pypi.org/project/keyring/

Comment: @jottbe Yes, it is .